# How to make Brill use lining figures in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context, opentype, number

There's another question but it uses regular LaTeX instead of ConTeXt. I've tried but idk how to make this font have lining numerals. I checked via an online website to see that it is possible.

```
    \starttypescript [brill]
        \definefontsynonym[Brill-Roman]    [file:Brill-Roman]
        \definefontsynonym[Brill-Italic]     [file:Brill-Italic]
      \definefontsynonym[Brill-Bold]       [file:Brill-Bold]
        \definefontsynonym[Brill-BoldItalic] [file:Brill-BoldItalic]
    \stoptypescript

    \starttypescript [brill]
        \setups[font:fallback:serif]
        \definefontsynonym[Serif]                [Brill-Roman]    [features=default]
        \definefontsynonym[SerifItalic]          [Brill-Italic]     [features=default]
        \definefontsynonym[SerifBold]            [Brill-Bold]       [features=default]
        \definefontsynonym[SerifBoldItalic]      [Brill-BoldItalic] [features=default]
    \stoptypescript

    \starttypescript [brill]
        \definetypeface [brill]    [rm] [serif] [brill]    [default]
    \stoptypescript

    \definefontfeature[default][default][lnum=yes]

    \setupbodyfont[brill]
    
    \setupbodyfont[12pt]
```

Comment: I get lining numerals with your code when I add content, both with latest ConTeXt and with the version in TeXLive24.

Comment: Can you show it to me? I tried everything.

Comment: Not much to show, but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmC08.png). I think you rather need to detail a bit what version you use (of context and the font) and how you compile and so on.

Comment: So I use the latest ConTeXt version, i'm using the font already installed on my computer and not putting it into ConTeXt. I put my files in a project, product, component pipeline. Also the --- and -- are not converting into em and en dashes respectively.

Comment: The `--` and `---` work here (but I think `|--|` and `|=|` might be preferable). If I were you I'd try with the latest Brill to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, remove everything and start back from scratch:

```
\definefontfamily [brill] [rm] [Brill]

\definefontfeature[default][default][lnum=yes]

\setupbodyfont[brill]

\starttext

Numbers: 0123456789

En dash: --

Em dash: ---

\stoptext
```